# What to use in a Razor Inline express when you have to attach another fixed string

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

What is the best practice when you have to use a razor variable but you cannot have a space after it ?

eg.

```
@foreach (var photo in Model.Photos)
{
        <a style="width:@photo.ThumbWidth px;" href="..."><img....></a>
}
```

I don't want the space before "px"

- a method in the Model class that build the string ?
- String.Concat ?
- String interpolation with $ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses:

```
@foreach (var photo in Model.Photos) {
        <a style="width:@(photo.ThumbWidth)px;" href="..."><img....></a> 
}
```